# How to use SwissEPH to get Sun and Moon longitude?

Tags: java, android

I am a real amateur to writing android java code but I am slowly teaching myself so I am trying to write an app which calculates the [Tithi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithi), for a specific date and time which requires the longitude of the Sun and Moon. I have found a few project files of others on GITHUB which I have tried to understand and use but can not seem to get the details from SWISSEPH, I have added the swisseph jar file to the dependencies. The following is the code I tried adapting from, Please Help:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import swisseph.DblObj;
import swisseph.SweConst;
import swisseph.SweDate;
import swisseph.SwissEph;

public class PanchangBasicsCalculator {
    private static String yoga, tithi, karana;
    private static double diff,
        sum,
        location_lon,
        location_lat,
        sunLon,
        moonLon;
    private static PanchangBasics panch_basics;
    //private static SwissEph sw;
    public static PanchangBasics calculatePanchangBasics(
        SwissEph sw,
        double tjd_ut,
        double location_lon,
        double location_lat,
        Planet sun,
        Planet moon,
        int birthday,
        double offset
        ) {
        panch_basics = new PanchangBasics();
        sunLon = sun.getLongitude();
        moonLon = moon.getLongitude();
        diff = getDiff(sunLon, moonLon);
        sum = getSum(sunLon, moonLon);
        int nak_no =calculateNakshatra(moonLon);
        panch_basics.setNakshathra(Constants.nakshatra[nak_no]);
        panch_basics.setNakshatra_count(nak_no+1);
        panch_basics.setPada(calculatePada(diff));
        panch_basics.setDay(calculateDay(birthday));
        panch_basics.setYoga(calculateYoga(sum));
        panch_basics.setTithi(calculateTithi(diff));
        panch_basics.setKarana(calculateKarana(diff));
        panch_basics.setSunrise(
            calculateSunrise(sw, location_lon, location_lat, tjd_ut,offset));
        panch_basics.setSunset(
            calculateSunset(sw, location_lon, location_lat, tjd_ut,offset));
        panch_basics.setAyanamsa(calculateAyanamsa(sw, tjd_ut));
        Date sunrise =panch_basics.getSunrise().getTime();
        Date sunset =panch_basics.getSunset().getTime();
        int diffSec = (int)((sunset.getTime()-sunrise.getTime())/1000);
        int period=diffSec/8;
        //System.out.println("period"+period);
        
        panch_basics.setRahukal(calulateRange(sunrise,sunset,birthday,Constants.rahu,period));
        panch_basics.setYamaganda(calulateRange(sunrise,sunset,birthday,Constants.yamaganda,period));
        panch_basics.setGulika(calulateRange(sunrise,sunset,birthday,Constants.gulika,period));
        
        
        return panch_basics;
    }
    
    private static double getDiff(double sunLon, double moonLon) {
        double diff = moonLon - sunLon;
        if (diff < 0)
            diff = diff + 360;
        return diff;
    }

    public static String calculateTithi(double diff) {
        int ti = (int) (diff / 12)-1;
        //classical calculation involves adding a one here; stripped because of array positions
        if(ti<0){
            ti=0;
        }
        String[] tithiNames =
            {
                "1. Pratipat",
                "2. Dvitiya",
                "3. Tritiya",
                "4. Chaturthi",
                "5. Panchami",
                "6. Shashti",
                "7. Saptami",
                "8. Ashtami",
                "9. Navami",
                "10. Dashami",
                "11. Ekadashi",
                "12. Dvadashi",
                "13. Trayodashi",
                "14. Chaturdashi",
                "15. Purnima",
                "1. Pratipat",
                "2. Dvitiya",
                "3. Tritiya",
                "4. Chaturthi",
                "5. Panchami",
                "6. Shashti",
                "7. Saptami",
                "8. Ashtami",
                "9. Navami",
                "10. Dashami",
                "11. Ekadashi",
                "12. Dvadashi",
                "13. Trayodashi",
                "14. Chaturdashi",
                "15. Amavasya" };
        if (ti < 15)
            tithi = tithiNames[ti] + ", " + "Shukla paksha";
        else if (15 <= ti)
            tithi = tithiNames[ti] + ", " + "Krishna paksha";
        return tithi;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I went by get the longitude of the sun and moon using swisseph:

```
 private TextView txtBox;
    int Year, Month, Day, isun, imoon, iflag;
    double Hour,Min,julDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Year = 2021;
        Month = 02;
        Day = 10;
        Hour = 14;
        Min = 30;

        julDay = SweDate.getJulDay(Year,Month,Day,Hour);

        isun = SweConst.SE_SUN;
        imoon = SweConst.SE_MOON;
        iflag = SweConst.SEFLG_SWIEPH;
        double [] xx = new double[6];
        StringBuffer serr = new StringBuffer();

        SwissEph sw = new SwissEph();
        int sunLon = sw.swe_calc_ut(julDay,isun,iflag,xx[0],serr);
        int moonLon = sw.swe_calc_ut(julDay,imoon,iflag,xx[0],serr);

        txtBox = this.findViewById(R.id.txtBox);
        txtBox.setText(
                "GDate" + Day + "/" + Month + "/" + Year +
                "JDate" + julDay +
                "Sun Long" + sunLon +
                "Moon Long" + moonLon
        );
```